# How to configure and use specific loggers in python based upon logger name

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to configure multiple loggers within my application so that loggers in a particular sub-module of my application will send messages across the HTTPHandler and other areas of my application will not.  Essentially the longer processing sections will send input to the HTTPHandler in order to inform the user of the processing that is going on.  Ideally i would like to do this based upon the module name and configure the logger based upon the module name.  e.g. qualname=application.processing.*
However I cannot even seem to do basic control of loggers based upon a hard coded name.

I've attempted configuration both through fileConfig and dictConfig as you can see in the code below.

```py
import logging
import logging.config
import ruamel.yaml as yaml


def main():

    #logging_config_file = "logging.yaml"
    # try:
    #     with open(logging_config_file) as configuration_file:
    #         logger_dict = {}
    #         logger_dict = yaml.load(configuration_file)
    #         logging.config.dictConfig( logger_dict )
    # except Exception as y:
    #     print( "Unable to configure logging (", y, ") attempting Config file setup")
    try:
        logging.config.fileConfig( "logging.conf")
    except Exception as y:
        print( "Unable to configure logging (", y, ") attempting Config file setup")

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.debug( "in main" )

    logger2 = logging.getLogger( "ONLY_ME")
    logger2.info( "using only me")


    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
[loggers]
keys=root, webApp

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler,httpHandler

[formatters]
keys=

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_webApp]
level=DEBUG
qualname='ONLY_ME'
handlers=fileHandler,httpHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
args=('webAppLogging.log',)
propagate=0

[handler_httpHandler]
class=handlers.HTTPHandler
level=INFO
args=("localhost:8080","/","GET",)
propagate=0
```

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: false

handlers:
  console_handler:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
  file_handler:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    filename: webAppLogging.log
    propagate: false
  http_handler:
    level: INFO
    class: logging.handlers.HTTPHandler
    host: localhost:8080
    url: /
    method: GET
    propagate: false

root:
  handlers: [console_handler]
  level: DEBUG

loggers:
  webApp:
    qualname: ONLY_ME
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [file_handler, http_handler]
```

I would expect with the code and the configuration that on console I would see:
'in main'

and in the file and the http message i would see:
'using only me'

Instead i see in console:
'in main'
'using only me'

and I see nothing in webAppLogging.log nor do i see any http message traffic.

If i set the handlers into the root logger then i see messages in the log and in the http message traffic

I feel like I am missing something simple here.  Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue(s).  In both cases it was the syntax of the config/yaml file in regards to what logging  is expecting.  In the case of the .config
`qualname='ONLY_ME'`
should be
`qualname=ONLY_ME`
the '' was throwing it off

In the case of the yaml it appears the the logger name is acting as the "qualname" from the config and the "qualname:" doesn't appear to do anything.  changing
`webApp:` to `ONLY_ME:` seems to affect the behavior.

In terms of the desired effect children will inherit their parent logger if they dont' have a specific one defined for them.  e.g. onlyme.process and onlyme.display will both use the common logger of "onlyme" if it is defined either in the configuration or earlier in the program.